# How might I write a query to rank race results in the top 25 for a leaderboard?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an SQL table for a sporting event that lists the results something like this:

**Race**: 100m Sprint

**Name**: John Smith 
**Place**: 1

**Name**: Gabriel Donaldson 
**Place**: 2

**Name**: Alex Sanders 
**Place**: 3

---

**Race**: High Jump 150 m

**Name**: Alex Sanders 
**Place**: 1

**Name**: John Smith 
**Place** 2

**Name**: Gabriel Donaldson 
**Place**: 3

---

etc ...

Within a single sporting event the names of different people might be reused for different races. From all the races how might I write an SQL query to rank the top 10 or 25 etc top ranked people from the pool of contestants?

I should add that performance isn't an issue here because this is for personal use and not meant to scale.

Comment: Can you please rephrase to state clearly what actually you want?

Comment: Please provide table samples and what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Place)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY SUM(Place) ASC
LIMIT 10    -- or 25, or 15, etc.
```

This query aggregates place rankings for each contestant, and then sorts total rankings in descending order.  The top contestants should have the lowest total rankings.

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't we use asc order instead?